# wordpress .post() 500 server error

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I am still learning Wordpress and I am using .post() function to get the content of a specific post id. when ever I try to echo the ID I have no problem in the output. but when I try to fetch the content the console always throws a 500 (internal server error).

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

here is my code.

```html
<div class="container inner-container">
  <div class="col-sm-3 col-md-3 sidebar">
    <h4 class="bold"><?php echo $cat_name; ?></h4>
    <hr>
    <nav class="side-nav">
      <ul>
        <?php $posts=q uery_posts( array( 'post_type'=>'post', 'posts_per_page' => 5, 'order' => 'desc', 'orderby' => 'post_date', 'category_name' => $cat_slug) ); ?>

        <?php foreach($posts as $p): ?>
        <li class="view-content" value="<?php echo $p->ID; ?>">
          <?php echo $p->post_title; ?><span class="hover-arrow-right"><i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i></span>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-9 col-md-9">
    <div class="inner-content">


    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

this is the jquery.

```js
jQuery('.view-content').click(function(event) {
  var content = jQuery(this).val();
  event.preventDefault();
  jQuery.post('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/content-from-ajax.php', {
    content_id: content,
  }, function(res) {

    jQuery('.inner-content').html(res);

  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

and here is the file that i assigned in .post() function.

```html
<?php

 $content_id = $_POST['content_id'];

 echo $content_id;

?>
```

thank you in advance.

sorry for my bad engish grammar.

Comment: Concerning your english: just start sentences with uppercase letters. That would improve readability a lot.

Comment: Check webserver and php logfiles

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
$html = '';
    $posts= new WP_Query(
     array( 'post_type'=>'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'order' => 'desc',
            'orderby' => 'post_date',
            'category_name' => $cat_slug )
         ); ?>
    <?php  while ( $posts->have_posts() ) : $posts->the_post();  
    $html .= '<li class="view-content" value="'.get_the_ID().'">'
              .get_the_title().
           '<span class="hover-arrow-right">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-right"></i>
          </span>
    </li>';
    endwhile;
  echo $html;
  die();
```

Comment: you have to create one function in your function.php file and write this code in it after that you have to pass "action : function_name" in your jquery.post options and in return you will get the response.
Follow this link it will help you https://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins